# I have an Angular version 1.x directive I'm trying to unit test to see if html is rendered by my directive, but my ng-if is causing issues

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have a Angular 1 directive I'm trying to unit test to see if html is rendered but my ng-if is causing issues.

I'm finding that the html in the ng-if isnt rendering, so when I check to see if the html is rendered in my test, I then find its blank when I console log this.

I'm using angular version 1 not 2.
I'm using basic javascript and jasmine for my unit test.

//This is the ng-if causing the trouble at the top: **ui-gmap-google-map ng-if="initMap"**

I'm trying to set scope.initMap to true in the "beforeEach" then I compile and digest hoping that the view will render for my unit test to pass.

**This is my directive HTML I'm testing:**

```
    <ui-gmap-google-map ng-if="initMap" center="config.map.center" zoom="config.map.zoom" options="config.map.options" events="config.map.events" draggable="true">

        <ui-gmap-polygon path="compatiblePolygon" stroke="polygonConfig.stroke" fill="polygonConfig.fill" fit="true" static="true" visible="polygonConfig.visible" editable="polygonConfig.editable" draggable="polygonConfig.draggable" clickable="true" events="polygonConfig.events">
        </ui-gmap-polygon>

        <ui-gmap-markers models="compatiblePoints" coords="'self'" idKey="'id'"
            options="pointsConfig.options"
            clickable="true"
            doRebuildAll = "true">
        </ui-gmap-markers>

    </ui-gmap-google-map>

    <div class="styling-guide">
        <div class="styler styling-polygon"></div>
        <div class="styler styling-points"></div>
        <div class="styler styling-points availabilities"></div>
        <div class="styler styling-points investment-deals"></div>
        <div class="styler styling-points occupational-deals"></div>
    </div>
```

**This is my unit test for that directive:**

```
"use strict";

describe("map component:", function () {

    var element,
        scope,
        otherScope,
        map,
        mockMarker = {
            key: 15
        },
        mockPolygon = {
            setMap: function () {},
            getPath: function () {}
        },
        mockMapData = {},
        polygon = mockMapData.polygon.path,
        mockMapInstance = {
            map: {
                fitBounds: function () {}
            }
        },
        mockUIGmapIsReadyPromise =  function() {
            return {
                then: function (callback) {
                    var mockInstance = {
                        reduce: function () {
                            return mockMapInstance;
                        }
                    };
                    callback(mockInstance);
                }
            }
        };

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module("eg.directives"));

    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile, $window, uiGmapIsReady) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();

        uiGmapIsReady.promise = mockUIGmapIsReadyPromise;

        scope.polygon = polygon;

        element = "<map polygon=\"polygon\"></map>";
        element = $compile(element)(scope);

        angular.element(document.body).append(element);

        scope.$digest();

        map = element.find("ui-gmap-google-map");

        otherScope = scope;

        scope = element.isolateScope();

        scope.initMap = true;
    }));

    it("should produce a map", function () {
        expect(map[0].outerHTML).toContain("ui-gmap-google-map");
        expect(map.length).toEqual(1);
    });

});
```

**This is my directive I'm testing (main part of it):**

```
                function initMap() {
                    scope.initMap = false;

                    $timeout(function() {
                        scope.initMap = true;
                    });
                };

                //Called when map renders the html marker
                uiGmapIsReady.promise(1).then(function(instances) {
                    scope.convertPolygon();
                    scope.convertPoints();
                    const map = instances.reduce(function(previous, current) {
                        // We only have once instance
                        return current.map;
                    });

                    $rootScope.mapInstance = map;

                    $timeout(function() {
                        if (scope.compatiblePolygon.length > 0) {
                            scope.fitBoundPolygon();
                        }
                    });
                    // Notify
                    scope.isMapVisible = true;
                    $rootScope.$broadcast("map:rebroadcastActivePoints");
                });

                //Build / init map
                initMap();
```

Comment: I keep getting this error message when I run the tests: "'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'map[0].outerHTML')"